# ASP .Net Core saving IdentityUser Id as foreign key causes FK violation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have extended IdentityUser with new columns in a class AppUser.

```
 public class AppUser: IdentityUser
    {
        
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
       
    }
```

In another model I create a foreign key and navigation property for AppUser as follows:

```
 public abstract class TestEntity
    {


        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual AppUser User { get; set;}


    }
```

Then to save I use the following code:

```
 testEntity.UserId = this.userManager.GetUserId(Request.HttpContext.User);
 await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The error I get says:

```
Detail: Key (UserId)=(636511f2-a17b-47ef-9849-acb26a2ddd96) is not present in table "AppUser".
```

However, this key is present as an ID in the AspNetUsers table.. **Perhaps its important to mention that TestEntity is in a different Database Context from AppUser.**

Comment: TestEntity is an abstruct class which could not be instanced.how did you add the migration?

Comment: Sorry about that I had to minimise the code as I am using the repo pattern, Forgot to remove the abstract keyword.. So there the abstract keyword is not there..

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates: there is no corresponding row in the table AppUser where the column UserId contains the value 636511f2-a17b-47ef-9849-acb26a2ddd96

Then I created another Dbcontext  as you mentioned and add migration and updated database,
The database :

[image]

The AppUser table didn't share the data with that in your IdentityDbContext,so the error occured,you should keep them in the same Dbcontext

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Will push for them to be co-placed in the same context. Thought there was a way to attach an object from one context to another or something like that..